# YII How to convert a CHtml::link into a bootstrap.widgets.BootButton?

Tags: arrays, twitter-bootstrap, yii

i came across a little quest i am trying to convert this link that i worte in YII into a yii.bootstrap button but with very little success. I looked for a solution in the documentation on the bootstrap page but with no results so iam hoping someone here will point me in the right direction.

so the code for the link is as follows :

```
<?php echo CHtml::link(
        'delete', 
        '#', 
        array(
            'submit'=>'', 
            'params'=>array(
                'Price[command]'=>'delete', 
                'Price[id]'=>$id, 
                'noValidate'=>true)
            ));?>
```

The code for the yiibotstrap button is as follows :

```
 <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.BootButton', array(
            'buttonType'=>'submit', 
            'type'=>'primary', 
            'icon'=>'ok white',
            'label'=>'Submit',
            // '', 'large', 'small' or 'mini'
)); ?>
```

By the way iam programming in YII (php framework)

Comment: which extension? can you add the link? coz there are many extensions with similar functionalities

Comment: http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/#bootButton  this is the extension

Comment: are you getting any errors? what is the output? you want us to guess it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.BootButton', array(
            'buttonType'=>'submitLink', 
            'type'=>'primary', 
            'icon'=>'ok white',
            'label'=>'Submit',
            'htmlOptions'=>array(
              'submit'=>'', 
              'params'=>array(
                'Price[command]'=>'delete', 
                'Price[id]'=>$id, 
                'noValidate'=>true)
            ),
)); ?>
```

Comment: any idea how i could turn this into a buutButton ; $this->widget('Relation', array(
'model' => $model,
'relation' => 'products',
'parentObjects' => Product::model()->findAll('id_contract='.$model->id_contract),
'fields' => 'product_name',
'showAddButton' => false,
));

Comment: What is `Relation`? i didnt find any widget class named `Relation`